# I have made a calculator app but i also want brackets and operators functionality

Tags: html

i have made a calculator with react in functional  component by using hooks and useState but in calculator i also want brackets functionality if open single brackets"(" come in result then he will be multiply and also want operators replace functionality if 8*- then multiply operator replace with subtraction

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow. Please reconsider your question and take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
This board is about helping others with their coding-problems. What have you done so far? Please show us the codelines you have written so far concerning the problem. If you have errors or warnings please show them to us as well. You are expected to first make an honest attempt at solving a task by yourself.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.